# Azure AD Graph - AppRole Creation using Application Credential Flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am creating a new role in azure application using Azure AD Graph API. what i'm doing is getting access token from azure using this code:

```
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceID, clientCredential);
return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

And Creating Role using following code:

```
//Fetch application Data from azure AD
IApplication application = await activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(RoleModel.ApplicationID).ExecuteAsync();
AppRole NewRole = new AppRole
{
    Id = CurrentRoleID,
    IsEnabled = true,
    AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "User" },
    Description = RoleModel.RoleDescription,
    DisplayName = RoleModel.RoleName,
    Value = RoleModel.RoleName
 };
 application.AppRoles.Add(NewRole as AppRole);
 await application.UpdateAsync();
```

I also granted **All Application Permissions** not the Delegated Permissions from Azure portal to Microsoft Graph API. But i'm getting this error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"e4187318-4b72-49fb-903d-42d419b65778","date":"2019-02-21T13:45:23"}}

**Note:** 
I'm able to create new user and updated a user using this access token though.

**For Testing:**
For testing purpose, I granted Delegated Permissions to application and use client credential flow to get access token of current logged-in user and if the signed in user had enough directory role he/she can created role in application this is working fine.

**Question:**
So, is it possible to create a new role in application using application credential flow? if so, am i missing something?

**Updated:**
Added all Application Permission for API **Windows Azure Active Directory** and Grant admin consent.

[image]

**Access Token:**
Access Token returned from ADzure AD

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: So, is it possible to create a new role in application using
>   application credential flow? if so, am i missing something?

Answer to your general question is **Yes**, you can add a new role to application's roles using Azure AD Graph API and client credentials flow.

**Working Code**

Given below is the working code (it's a quick and dirty console application, just to make sure I test it before confirming)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace AddAzureADApplicationRoles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/{myTenantId}"),
                async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

            //Fetch application Data from azure AD
            IApplication application = activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId("{MyAppObjectId}").ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            AppRole NewRole = new AppRole
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                IsEnabled = true,
                AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> {"User"},
                Description = "My Role Description..",
                DisplayName = "My Custom Role",
                Value = "MyCustomRole"
            };

            application.AppRoles.Add(NewRole as AppRole);
            application.UpdateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
        {
            string TokenForApplication = "";

                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MyTenantId}",
                    false);

                // Configuration for OAuth client credentials 

                    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("{AppId}",
                        "{AppSecret}"
                        );
                    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
                        await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCred);
                    TokenForApplication = authenticationResult.AccessToken;                

            return TokenForApplication;
        }
    }
}
```

**Probable Issue behind your specific exception**

I think you have given application permissions on Microsoft Graph API, instead of permissions required for Azure AD Graph API.

While setting required permissions for your application, in Select an API dialog, make sure you select "Windows Azure Active Directory" and not "Microsoft Graph". I am giving screenshot for more detail next.

**Steps to give required permissions**

Notice that my app doesn't require any permissions on "Microsoft Graph API". It only has application permissions given for "Windows Azure Active Directory".

So, choose the appropriate application permission for your requirement, and make sure you do "Grant Permissions" at the end to provide Admin consent, as all the application permissions here mention Requires Admin as Yes.

[image]

On a side note, when you first create an app registration, it already has one delegated permission on Windows Azure Active Directory, so you may not need to explicitly select Windows Azure Active Directory again (unless you've removed it for your app), but just select the correct application permissions and do Grant Permissions as an administrator.

Comment: #Rohit Updated the permissions as you told. But still getting insufficient privileges. Updated the question with Permission and Token section.

Comment: Also, using user credentials "UserID" and "Password" and giving proper permissions    roles will be created in application without any issue.

Comment: @umer I compared the token my working app is getting with the one you posted in your edit, both look very similar. Only difference is that my token has only one role "Application.ReadWrite.All" as I only selected that one application permission (see screenshot in my answer). If it isn't too much disruption for you, try to remove all other permissions from your app registration's required permissions temporarily and see if that makes any difference.. My app registration details and code is shared as part of answer already which works at my end, not sure what else is the difference in your case

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was busy in some office stuff. yesterday I give permissions that u mentioned and everything seems to be working fine. Thank for help.